# Multiple DNS manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, namecheap, netlify

Both AWS route 53 and Netlify want me to add their NS1 hosts to my Custom DNS. Is it fine to have both of them in my Custom DNS list?

Namecheap:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Derek said, you'll need to pick one nameserver, and then put all of your records on that service (including the records on the service you don't pick).

Either service will work for your Netlify site, but if you want to serve your site from the apex domain (i.e. `example.com`, without the `www`), Route 53 only supports a standard A record for that purpose. The downside to an A record is that you have to specify a single IP address, which means visitors don't get the benefits of a CDN on their initial DNS lookup, and you also introduce a single point of failure ([more info](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/02/28/to-www-or-not-www/)).

As mentioned in the linked article, some other DNS services offer alternate record types to work around the A record limitation. If you use Netlify DNS, it can handle the apex domain as if it had a CNAME record, automatically routing to the visitor's nearest CDN node, and avoiding the single point of failure.

If you *don't* need to serve the apex domain, then a CNAME record will work fine on either service.

Comment: I want to point my domain to Netlify to host my static site. I also have a lot of sub-domains that point to Amplify with other web apps on them. If I change my NS to Netlify how will that affect the existing or new sub-domains? My website has three environments so it includes apex and sub-domains too.

Answer (score 2):

A nameserver (NS) record should point to an **authoritative** DNS server for your domain.  Presumably, your Route 53 and Netlify DNS Servers would have different records, so depending on how the client resolves the domain of your site, they could get different records (and thus be unable to access your site).

Instead, you need to delegate one (probably Route 53) as the authoritative name server, and find a different way (such as a subdomain) to redirect traffic to netlify.